# Instantiating a socket (is it a bad practice or not ?)

Tags: c++, sockets, asio

I need to do a server-client architecture for an university project and i'm stuck at the sockets part. I thought that i can instantiate the whole server once, then call the socket whenever needed, but, if i do this, whenever i run the server, nothing happens on the client side, unless i specify it to write something in the moment of instantiation.

The code for the instantiated socket:

```
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using asio::ip::tcp;

class ServerSocket
{
public:
    ServerSocket(ServerSocket& otherSingleton) = delete;
    void operator=(const ServerSocket& copySingleton) = delete;

    static tcp::socket* GetInstance();

private:
    static ServerSocket* instance;
    tcp::socket* socket;

    ServerSocket()
    {
        std::cout << "Server started";
        try
        {
            asio::io_context io_context;

            tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 13));

            for (;;)
            {
                tcp::socket socket(io_context);
                acceptor.accept(socket);
            }
        }
        catch (std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    ~ServerSocket()
    {
        std::cout << "Server closed";
    }
};
```

and its cpp

```
ServerSocket* ServerSocket::instance(nullptr);

tcp::socket* ServerSocket::GetInstance()
{
    if (instance == nullptr)
    {
        instance = new ServerSocket();
    }
    return instance->socket;
}
```

I was thinking that actually i need to instantiate the acceptor and specify a socket in my function, ex:

```
void DBUser::SendUser()
{
    ServerSocket* instance; 
    tcp::socket* socket = instance->GetInstance();
    try
    {
        //instead of trying to write directly in the function i should call the acceptor again 
        //and create a socket on the spot
        asio::error_code ignored_error;
        asio::write(*socket, asio::buffer(m_user), ignored_error);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

if anyone can help me understand what i'm doing wrong and how i can fix it i'd appreciate it

Comment: You accept a new connection into a local socket object, and then immediately close it (as it goes out of scope).  I'd recommend you to read asio examples carefully.

Comment: Besides, note that you never initialize `ServerSocket::socket` member.